# POSTFIX how to use a relayserver just for a specific domain?

Tags: postfix

I have two email servers: `mx1.example.com` (IMAP, SMTP) and `mx2.example.com` (SMTP gateway).

- `mx1.example.com` is handling email for `example.com`,
  `example.net` and `example.org`.
- `mx2.example.com` is configured as a gateway for `mx1.example.com`
  (I want him to send out all mails that originate from
  `mx1.example.com`)

Now I want to send the emails

- from `example.com` and `example.net` via `mx1.example.com` normally
- from `example.org` via `mx1.example.com` (password auth) to the gateway  `mx2.example.com` (IP).

How can I configure this?

UPDATE: Please hurry up guys, the bounty expires in 2 days.

To be more clear:
I know how to relay via `mx2.example.com` (how to send everything via mx2.)
I just have to put the IP of mx2 in relayhost in the main.cf in mx1. But I want to make this selectively, just for example.org.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot use transport as it is used to transport emails to the MAILBOX, you need to use

```
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps
```

it works like this in your **main.cf**:

```
relayhost = mx1.example.org, mx2.example.org 
relay_domains = example.com, example.org, example.net

smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relaymap
```

**/etc/postfix/relaymap** looks like this :

```
@example.com    mx1.example.com
@example.net    mx1.example.com

@example.org    mx2.example.com
```

Comment: Need to put all config or with smtp_sender and sender_dependent it's ok?

Comment: Only configuring relay_domains it's enough riight?

Comment: I get the following error message ```postmap: fatal: relayhost parameter setting must not contain multiple values: example1.mail.protection.outlook.com, example2.mail.protection.outlook.com```

Answer (score 1):

by using the selective relay feature:

#### on mx1.example.com:

- add a line : `example.org        smtp:mx2.example.com` to **/etc/postfix/transport**
- add a line : `transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport` to **/etc/postfix/main.cf**
- run `postmap /etc/postfix/transport`
- run `postfix reload`

#### on mx2.example.com :

- add `mx1.example.com` to mynetworks  in **/etc/postfix/main.cf**
- make sure you have something like:

  `smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination`
  in **/etc/postfix/main.cf**  it is missing
- run `postfix reload`

Postfix to relay mails to other SMTP for particular domain

http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html

http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#lists

https://xdeb.org/post/2017/12/20/mail-relay-mx-backup-and-spam-filtering-with-postfix/

https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/postfix-relay-one-domain-to-smarthost-a-all-else-to-smarthost-b.62955/

http://verchick.com/mecham/public_html/spam/relay_recipients.html

Comment: for some reason it is not working. I followed your proposal exactly It does not send the example.org via the mx2. It sends it out via mx1 like all other.

Comment: please look in your `/var/log` folder , there should be files named ''mail.err mail.log` , in which you find essential information on what went  wrong , please also check with `postconf -n` or by manually looking into the files that there is no parameter duplicate , also we might start a chat and you could send snippets of logs as suggested here : https://serverfault.com/questions/466461/postfix-transport-not-getting-triggered

Answer (score 0):

Check, this settings must be:

```
mydestination =
relayhost =
```